# Работа с JSONs в postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Имеется папка с json файлами, которые нужно импортировать в таблицу для парсинга силами sql. Как можно импортировать все файлы разом, триггер или sh скрипт.
Сырые json'ы лежат в колонке consumers - это делал через пайтон, но он сильно исказил json и они стали не читабельны для sql.
[image: Примерно так должно быть после импорта]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как минимум проблема в кавычках. Попробуйте заменить одинарные кавычки на двойные `replace(consumers, E'\'', '"')::jsonb`. А в питоне проблема очевидно в том, что делали просто `str(d)` где `d` - dict. Так вы не получаете json. Чтоб получить json используйте `dumps` из модуля json

Comment: Понял, кавычки сразу бросаются в глаза. Самое интересное, что делал питоном через dumps - как вы советуете.

Comment: Нужно смотреть код, что-то не так делали с dumps - у вас на выходе невалидный json, dumps создает правильный.

Comment: Понял. Большое спасибо! Буду разбираться с питоновской частью. А как можно реализовать импорт нескольких json'ов через SQL в одну таблицу нет идей?